# apache VirtualHost redirecting to different VirtualHost

Tags: apache

I am very new to `Apache2` and I am attempting to serve two websites on a server.

I have followed the documentation here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

and have attempted:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "var/www/websiteexample1.com"
    ServerName www.websiteexample1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "var/www/websiteexample2.com"
    ServerName www.websiteexample2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

However if i attempt to go to `www.websiteexample2.com` I am instead directed to the content of `www.websiteexample1.com`

What am i missing?

Comment: Are you trying to set `DocumentRoot` path as relative to Apache install dir? Are you using Apache/2.4?

Comment: Hello, 

I am using absolute directory paths. The version of Apache i am using is 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: When using name based virtual hosts, if for some reason a VirtualHost isn't matched, then Apache will send the request to the first VirtualHost it found in the configuration file. This doesn't help you, but may in part explain why your request ends up being handled by the first. Are these two VirtualHost definitions in the same file or separate? If in separate ``sites-available`` files, has the later site been enabled so linked into ``sites-enabled``? This presume on Linux and that structure is used.

Comment: I've got two .conf files in both sites-enabled and sites-available. That structure is used on Linux. This still has not resolved the issue.

Comment: The DocumentRoot values in your code above are _not_ absolute, they are missing a leading slash. Is that just a typo here or is that really what you have in your config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue may be that you have not setup an associated Directory in the main conf file? Something along the lines of :-

```
#======================================================================
# Note this one is for the secondary root (for www.websiteexample2.com
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.

<Directory "Your 2nd Website's Directory here">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You also need to tell Apache to use/look at the virtual hosts file. So if you haven't got the following, ensuring that it is not commented out and that it points to the correct location :-

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

*This based upon a 2.2.6 version of Apache*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I attempted to add that to my apache2.conf file. I still didn't make any difference after a restart.

Comment: Added an additional check